# What Rails associations to use and how to use them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, rails-api

I have a Rails API that currently has two models, `HelpCategory` and `HelpRequest`.

Each instance of `HelpRequest` can only be related to one instance of `HelpCategory`.
Each instance of `HelpCategory` can be related to many instances of `HelpRequest`.

When creating a new instance of `HelpRequest`, I want to be able to add the id of an instance of `HelpCategory` to `HelpRequest`.

For example, I would like to be able to do something like this.

```
HelpCategory.create!(title: "Help with Shopping")
# {id: 1, title: "Help with Shopping"}
HelpRequest.create!(title: "Please help me to collect my shopping", help_category_id: 1)
# {id: 4, title: "Please help me to collect my shopping", help_category_id: 1}
```

So that I could do something like

```
request = HelpRequest.find(4)
# {id: 4, title: "Please help me to collect my shopping", help_category_id: 1}
request.help_category.title
# "Help with Shopping"
```

Can someone please help me to understand how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

This is just your run of the mill one to many association.

```
class AddHelpCategoryIdToHelpRequest < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :help_requests, :help_categories, index: true
  end
end
```

This adds a `help_category_id` column to the `help_requests` table and a foreign key. Then add the associations:

```
class HelpRequest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :help_category
end

class HelpCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :help_requests
end
```

[`belongs_to`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) tells ActiveRecord that the foreign key is on *this* table. [*has_many*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) tells Rails that this model is referenced from the other table.

You can then assign the category by passing an id or a record:

```
help_category= HelpCategory.create!(title: "Help with Shopping")

hr = HelpRequest.create!(
  title: "Please help me to collect my shopping", 
  help_category: help_category
)
# This is primarily done indirectly through the params
hr = HelpRequest.create!(
  title: "Please help me to collect my shopping", 
  help_category_id: help_category.id
)
```

You can also just create/initialize records off the association:

```
hr = help_category.help_requests.create!(
  title: "Please help me to collect my shopping", 
)
```